# Strange behaviour when swapping numbers in a list and then using list comprehension

Tags: python

I am not really sure why this code does not swap the numbers as it was instructed to in the for loop. Instead, it doesn't change the order of the numbers in the list at all. Is there a reason it behaves that way?

Here is the code:

```
def foo():
    for i in range(len(L)):
        L[i], L[-1 - i] = L[-1 - i], L[i]

L = [i for i in range(10)]

foo()
print(L) # Output: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
# As opposed to 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

Comment: Have you tried any debugging?

Comment: put `print(L)` inside the loop and you will see immediately what's wrong

Comment: The list comprehension doesn't affect anything here. In any case, `L = [i for i in range(10)]` is an overly verbose way of writing `L = list(range(10))`

Comment: Why not use `L.reverse()` ?

Comment: What about: `L = list(reversed(range(10)))` ?

Comment: I am trying to familiarize myself with the concept of swapping in Python to later utilize it in more complex tasks such as implementing algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I am just not sure why the fact that I use len(L) in for 'for loop' is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you swapped them all, and then swapped them back again! When `i` is 1, you swap it with index 8, then when `i` is 8 you swap back to index 1. To understand exactly what happens when the program runs, it may help you to step through it using the excellent [Python Tutor website](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20foo%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20range%28len%28L%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20L%5Bi%5D,%20L%5B-1%20-%20i%5D%20%3D%20L%5B-1%20-%20i%5D,%20L%5Bi%5D%0A%0AL%20%3D%20%5Bi%20for%20i%20in%20range%2810%29%5D%0A%0Afoo%28%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=17&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

You need to swap index `i` with index `-1 - i` only when the first index is before the second in the list. The simplest fix is to change the range from `len(L)` to `len(L) // 2`, so the index `i` only goes halfway through the list, and the other index goes backwards through the other half.

Comment: That is quite strange. I'm not really sure I understand why does len(L) causes the following problem?

Comment: Well, suppose the list length is 10. When `i` is 1, the other index is 8, so you swap indices 1 and 8. Then when `i` is 8, the other index is 1, so you swap indices 8 and 1, undoing the previous swap. I'll edit the answer to include a link which may help.

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(L):
    for i in range(int(len(L)/2)):
        L[i], L[-i - 1] = L[-1 - i], L[i]


L = [i for i in range(10)]
foo(L)
print(L)
```

Comment: to swap 2 numbers [1, 2] you need one swap -> [2, 1]
to swap 4 numbers [1, 2, 3, 4] you need 2 swaps 1st swap will give you [4, 2, 3, 1] second swap [4, 3, 2, 1]

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes perfect sense!

Comment: this is why you go half of the length!